# Use angularjs module inside Angular 2

Tags: javascript, angular

there is some angularjs modules which is not available yet for Angular 2 like iranian special calendar:
https://amirkabirdataminers.github.io/ADM-dateTimePicker/

i was simply including its files like this :

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="myApp">
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/ADM-dateTimePicker.css" />
        <script src="js/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/ADM-dateTimePicker.min.js"></script>
        ...
    </head>
    <body>
        ...
    </body>
</html>
```

then injecting it:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ADM-dateTimePicker']);
```

and finally using it like:

```
<adm-dtp ng-model='date'></adm-dtp>
```

**Question:**
how can i code abow inside my angular 2 project (using typescript) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

seems finally someone done it !

https://fingerpich.github.io/jalali-angular-datepicker/

a very awesome and mature component for managing Jalali Date in angular 2 applications.

no need for old angularjs library anymore..

Answer (score 0):

Angular 2's architecture is completely different from Angular 1. Your code as such could not be programmed in Angular 2.

Try using angular start up code from angular.io site to get started. That will nice starting point to dive into angular 2.